# Grepping from a parameter file for non-matching text

Tags: shell-script, text-processing

I have a parameter file and I'm trying to grip a word and then remove only that word, leaving everything else. For instance:

An Example would be:

```
#Parameter File
CAT=SammyISaGreatCat
```

This is my string of code:

```
export CAT=`grep CAT $PARFILE | grep -Ev "CAT="`
```

I want `SammyIsaGreatCat` to be the only thing grabbed from the parameter file. How can I do this?

Comment: `cat=$(sed -n 's/^CAT=//p' < "$PARFILE")`

Comment: Do I put this in my parameter file Stephane? And what do I put in the actual script.

Comment: Don't change your parameter file. Stéphane is saying that instead of using `grep` use `sed`. So the command line you need is `export CAT=$(sed -n 's/^CAT=//p' < "$PARFILE")`.

Answer (score 0):

You can read the parameter with

```
export CAT=$(grep -i "^cat=" "${PARFILE}" | head -1 | cut -d= -f2-)
```

Additional checks is making cat case-insensitive and just returning the first when you have two lines with `CAT=`.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution with `awk`:

```
export CAT=$(awk -F= 'BEGIN{OFS=FS}$1~/^\W*CAT\W*$/{$1="";r=substr($0,1+length(FS))};
                        END{print r}' "$PARFILE")
```

This has the advantage of:

- Being flexible with optional whitespaces in the key, `\W*`, surrounding `CAT`.
- In case of multiple results, it only prints the last one.
- Works with `=` in the values.

  - First, set the output field separator to be the same as the input field separator (`OFS=FS`).
  - Clear the first field, and save the reconstructed line (`$0`) starting from after the first separator.